# Solr return file name

Tags: solr, indexing

I have indexed a couple of documents using solr, now when I perform a search using the admin interface, it returns search results in the XML format.

I am trying to figure out how can I associate a document that I have indexed example: test.pdf with the results that I receive and then serve that document to my user ?

Will solr return to me a unique ID of the document that I index, so that after indexing a document I can store the document along with that UID in my database somewhere and then when the user performs a search solr return the unique ID's of documents that match the search criteria and then I serve them from the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add the filename as a stored field. Look at your `schema.xml` and make sure you declare a field of type `string` and set the `stored` attribute to `true`. By setting `stored=true` you will ensure that Solr can return the field back in results.

See this page for more information: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml

Comment: I have added the following line to my schema.xml, and restarted solr.

   <field name="filename" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

then posted a document solr.xml using post.jar, the document got posted successfully but still no field by the name filename is returned in the search

Comment: Are you making sure to ask for the field back, what does your "field list" `fl` parameter. See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters

Comment: And are you sure that you are WRITING to the field. What is `post.jar` and how does it know about your new field?

Comment: ThIS may also be important http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Mapping_and_Capture . Use **literal.id** (generally literal.field_in_schema) to enter the id of your document. Then re-index those docs.

Comment: thank you Cody, I was not sending in the filename field in my search query, rectified that and now things are working.. thanks again!

Comment: @aitchnyu , yes initially I was not adding the literal. keyword, almost tore my hair apart!