# In Solr 4 - How do I include file names in the index?

Tags: solr, lucene, schema, xsd, solr-schema

I am building a search Engine with Solr 4.8.1 - in doing so, I am attempting to display the file names of each indexed document in my GUI search results.

I can successfully display any field that is in Solr's Schema.xml file (title, author, id, resourcename last_modified etc.). I cannot, however, find a field in the schema.xml that holds the name of the file (such as for the file Test.pdf the name "Test" or for Example.docx the word "Example")

The closest field I can find is "resourcename" which displays the entire file path in my system (ex. C:\Users\myusername\Documents\solr-4.8.1\example\exampledocs\filename.docx when all I want to display is filename.docx)

(1) How do I tell solr to index the name of a file?
or
(2) Is there a field that cover the file name that I am just missing?

Sincerest thanks!

---Research Update---
It seems this question is asking for the same thing - [Solr return file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390972/solr-return-file-name) - however, I do not believe that simply adding a field called "filename" will cause Solr to index the file name! I know I need to add a field to the Schema.xml file - now how do I point that field to the name of a file?

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much a question regarding `solr` functionality as it is about the tools you use to publish to solr. While adding a new field called fileName to solr will resolve part of the issue, modifying the publish tool to add the `testPDF.pdf` value to each . I guess i'd point my eyes at `Tika` : http://tika.apache.org/ , seeing how you mention both `pdf` and `doc` files.